How check if user is logged in on server side React, Django, JWT
I have set up authorization using the JWT token. Now I want to give the user access to the protected view, which requires authorization.
class GetUser(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def post(self, request):
        return Response({'username': request.user.username})

How do I check if the user is logged in on the server side? I wrote an asynchronous function that accesses the django rest framework api.  But this function always returns a promise no matter what I do.
function saveToken(data) {
  localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access)
  localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh)
  return true
}

async function isLoggedIn() {
  return await axios.post('api/getuser/', {}, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')}})
  .then(async function (response) { return true })
  .catch(async function (error) {
    return await axios.post('api/token/refresh/', {refresh: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')})
    .then(async function (response) { return saveToken(response.data) })
    .catch(async function (error) { return false })
  })
}

As I understand it, I can't get the value from promise in any way. That's why I decided to write the component this way, but React throws an error.
const ComponentMainArea = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const element = useOutlet()

  return isLoggedIn().then((value) => {
    if (!value) { return (<Navigate to="/proxy/8000/login"/>) }
    else {
      return (
        <div className='mainarea'>
          <AnimatePresence mode='wait' initial={true}>
            {element && React.cloneElement(element, { key: location.pathname })}
          </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
}

How do I implement server-side authorization verification?
I also tried to use this asynchronous function in useEffect, but promise does not allow me to work with it normally, or I do not know how to do it

As far as I know, local storage is not accessible on the server side. From what you've tried using useEffect, is it okay to implement logic on the client side?

User authentication is usually stored locally on the client (as it should be). It cannot be simply accessed server-side. You could pass the authentication token to the server to make it accessible there, but usually I would handle such things client-side.
Why do you need to render client specific things server side?

To me, i like to set the tokens in httpOnly cookies, to get the account infos i have a specific endpoint like /account/. Then i have a interceptor which does a token refresh call when i get a 401, if it fails i will navigate the user to the login page. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/why-cookie-is-preferable-compared-to-localstorage-when-it-comes-to-authentication-b43ac5610be6?gi=2846cdb23ef4
